# FileLoader cannot load the proper file

Tags: javascript, three.js

When I use the FileLoader, the data always return the code of the html, is there any wrong with the code?(the library makehuman-data has been correctly installed in the node_module)

```
                let loadUrls = {
                    modeling_sliders: 'node_modules/makehuman-data/src/json/sliders/modeling_sliders.json',
                    resources: 'node_modules/makehuman-data/public/data/resources.json'
                };
                Promise.all(
                    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
                    _.values(loadUrls).map((url) => new Promise((resolve) => {
                            loader.load(
                                url,
                                (data) => JSON.parse(data)
                            )
                        })
                    )
                )
```

[the result showed in the web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs6Qc.png)

Comment: Why not simply use `fetch` for these? And then `response.json()`? There is no requirement to use the THREE.js way. Also, your promise is never resolved. This should work if you `(data) => resolve(JSON.parse(data))` I guess?

Comment: The problem is that no matter i use ```fetch``` or ```FileLoader```, it cannot load the correct file, but the code of the html, and it should be ```resolve(JSON.parse(data))```. (and i use three.js cause i use FileLoader to init a config(resources in the code to generate a 3D model.

Comment: The problem has been solved, it turns out that I didn't put the file correct path. I should put it under the file public, instead of node_module.